# Importing and mapping custom data with dataflow

Tags: dataflow

I want to parse a csv, map the fields, and do perform some custom logic with the imported data, but I can't seem to figure out the Profile Actions XML.

The XML currently looks like this, along with my reasoning:

**=> Firstly the Adapter checks if the file exists and creates the batch model.**

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[stuff.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>
```

**=> Here the Parser parses the CSV and stores it into dataflow_import_data table for other actions to access/manipulate it.**

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>
```

**=> Here the mapper converts the data stored in the dataflow_import_data table.**

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
   <var name="map">
       <map name="first_name"><![CDATA[Given Name]]></map>
       <map name="last_name"><![CDATA[Family Name]]></map>
   </var>
   <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>
```

**=> And finally, I can perform my own logic. (this doesn't make much sense since the csv rows are already parsed, but there doesn't seem to be a right action for this.. )**

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">false</var>
    <var name="number_of_records">10</var>
    <var name="adapter">mymodule/convert_adapter_myadapter</var>
    <var name="method">saveRow</var>
</action>
```

Obviously, above won't work because (in the second action) convert_parser_csv doesn't have an adapter and method.

Can someone point me in the right direction to make the mapper work?

Comment: Was your question answered? Then please mark a solution.

Comment: @Erfan I hope you knew, "how to add import option to the custom module data?". Can you guide me or suggest any link for reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapper only works with exporting data. The [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/introduction-to-magento-dataflow) didn't mention that :(

I will map the fields myself in the saveRow method of my adapter. Following code works fine:

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[stuff.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">false</var>
    <var name="number_of_records">10</var>
    <var name="adapter">mymodule/convert_adapter_myadapter</var>
    <var name="method">saveRow</var>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly if this fits your needs, but maybe you should take a look at this extension: [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport). With FastSimpleImport you can use an array as source for Magento´s ImportExport Core Module. So, you could read your CSV (or any other source) into an array, manipulate the data and run the import.